# How to disable lock screen in ICS when VPN is set?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, lock-screens, vpn, password, sony-xperia-s

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connecting to VPN forces having secure screen lock](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22867/connecting-to-vpn-forces-having-secure-screen-lock)

I have **Sony Xperia S** with `ICS 4.0.4` stock rom **(rooted)**, I need to have a **VPN account** set in my phone, but when I add a VPN account, the phone asks me to set either a pattern or password for lock screen, which I don't want.

Is there an app or hack **to disable lock screen** or at least, have just simple `"slide to unclock"` instead of pattern or password?

Comment: You are probably looking for [Slide unlock till pattern lock gets activated after interval](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29832/slide-unlock-till-pattern-lock-gets-activated-after-interval) -- see my answer there to completely disable the lock (temporarily, of course).

Comment: @AlEverett thanks, that possible duplicate question didn't show up when I searched, and is for a different device than mine, BTW it helped me and I succeeded to disable lock screen completely.

Comment: Part of the problem here is that people use device-specific tags inappropriately. That makes things harder to find.