# Enable slide-lock without PIN/password prior to security timeout - PIN/password enforced by enterprise security policy

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, lock-screens

I'm on a Galaxy S2X on Jelly Bean 4.1.2, and my company's security policy forces me to use PIN or Password to unlock the device.

Jellybean now allows you to disable "Lock instantly with power button" - if you press the power button, it turns off the screen without locking. And then if you press the power button again before the security timeout, the screen turns back on, and you are not required to enter your password / PIN.

I want to change the behaviour so that if you press the power button, it enables the swipe lock; so if you press the power button again before the security timeout, you are required to swipe the screen to use the phone (prevents "butt-dialing", etc.). I would still want to require the password / PIN after the security timeout.

I've seen a number of posts on this with solutions that use Tasker and Secure Settings to enable and disable the password / PIN on certain conditions - example: [Slide unlock till pattern lock gets activated after interval](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29832/slide-unlock-till-pattern-lock-gets-activated-after-interval); but this solution does not work when you have a security policy that does not allow you to disable the password / PIN.

Is there another way to achieve this?

I was thinking that if there were some way to de-couple the "slide" from the actual "lock" (since locking always requires a password / PIN on my phone). Is there a way I can invoke the Android slide screen using Tasker without locking? Or, could I invoke a 3rd party slide screen?

Comment: Not sure about the S2X, but on my GS3, there's an option under lock screen called "lock automatically" that will not require the pin for X time (0 to 30 minutes) after the screen goes off.

Comment: Yes, I have "lock automatically" set for 5 mins, and "lock instantly with power button" disabled. So, if I press the power button the screen goes off, if I press the power button again within 5 mins, the screen comes on and I do not require a password. What I'm looking for is: if I press the power button again within 5 mins, I need to swipe to unlock the screen.

Comment: I have exactly the same scenario on my Moto X (4.2.2).  Until the PIN interval expires, pressing the power button directly turns the screen on, enabling accidental pocket dialing or app launching.   This is especially troubling when the screen is turned on by a phone call or SMS during this interval.

Answer (score -1):

I've found a workable solution for this problem. I installed [Go Locker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jiubang.goscreenlock), which is a custom slide screen lock. Follow its initial (somewhat confusing) instruction to disable unlocking with the home button, and enable Settings -> Visual Setting -> Hide status bar. Then when you press the power button to lock the phone, when you unlock you get the Go Locker screen. The only downside is after your security timeout, you'll have to enter your password/PIN and *then* slide to unlock with Go Locker.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, it's polite to leave a comment as to why you felt the answer was not a good one: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down .